# DIsplay Images from folder into website using the MVC framework

Tags: php

I wish to display an image in a website using PHP - MVC framework.  I've got the following in views:

```
echo("<img src=\images/test.jpg" />");
```

but all I am is getting a square coming up. Can someone give me a nudge in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: check your image path.. it should be forward slash
``echo("<img src=/images/test.jpg" />");``

Comment: Do I need to put something in the controller?

Comment: what MVC framework you are using?

Comment: which frame work are you using??

Comment: The framework is codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're still looking for an answer but I assume you have the image folder in your root.
Then you can display the image by adding base_url() to the path.

```
echo '<img src="' . base_url() . '/images/test.jpg" />';
```

(you where also missing a double quote for src=")